# "The _______________ passage of Time": a word that means unhalting, steady

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

What is a word that can be used to describe the slow yet unstoppable progress of time? Something like (but not exactly) inevitable. I remember reading this phrase in a book but the exact word evades my memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**inexorable**

> continuing without any possibility of being stopped
>
> - the inexorable progress of science

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inexorable)

Or in your case...

*The inexorable passage of time*.

Comment: +1 I have also heard "the inexorable _march_ of time"...BTW, you have racked up an impressive number of gold badges, mostly from review queue. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Just repeating what Cascabel has said: _Thank you for your efforts, @KillingTime._